# Jackson map JSON containing different items for same object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got the follwoing JSON structure with the corresponding DTOs in Java:

```
{
  "kind": "object 1",
  "selfLink": "some_link",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "subkind 1",
      "name": "server 1",

      "anotherObject": {
        "link": "some_link",
        "isSubcollection": true,
        "items": [
          {
            "att 1": "value",
            "att2": "value",
            "att3": "value"
          },
          {
            "att5": "value" ,
            "att6": "value" ,
            "att7": "value" ,
            "att8": "value"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to map this into corresponding `DTO`s using `Jackson`. Using the `@JsonIgnoreUnknown` annotation, this works fine. The problem is within the `items` array: How can I map different classes from the same JSON list in Jackson? Of course I could create a huge class containing both's attributes, but that would not be my way of choice.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: of course it is not, because I reduced it to the minimum that is needed to understand my problem:)

Comment: I've tried fixing the JSON, please rollback if it's not as it should be.

Comment: @ItFreak How you decide what class should be used to deserialize object?

Comment: @talex this is my key question. How can I differentiate the two classes that are of the same 'type' in the json

Comment: There are two `items` arrays btw, I guess you're talking about the deepest-nested one?

Comment: @ItFreak Only you know that. It depends on your data format.

Comment: Related but a bit more complex (there might be a simpler solution to your problem) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915356/json-deserialization-in-java-w-jackson-of-mixed-types-contained-in-one-array